# Determine eigenvalues and eigenvectors and exists a basis of eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, permutation-matrices

> Determine the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors of $$ A= \begin{pmatrix}  0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$ Can you find a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ consisting of eigenvectors of $A$?

---

The characteristic polynomial is

$ \lambda^2 (1-\lambda) -1 + \lambda = -\lambda^3 + \lambda^2 + \lambda -1 $

The roots are

$\lambda_{1,2} = 1 $ and $\lambda_3 = -1$

now calculating

$ (A - \lambda_{i}E_3) \cdot (x,y,z)^T = 0$

results in

$\begin{pmatrix} t\\t\\z \end{pmatrix}$ with $t,z \in \mathbb{R}$  for $\lambda_{1,2}$

and

$\begin{pmatrix} t\\-t\\0 \end{pmatrix}$ with $t \in \mathbb{R}$  for $\lambda_{3}$

therefore a possible basis would be

$ b_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\-1\\0 \end{pmatrix}$
$ b_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix}$
$ b_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\1 \end{pmatrix}$

Is this correct?

Comment: At first glance, yes!

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: This is indeed correct! Good job ;)